# idemia tablet for integration card readiing and fingerprint sdk

Tags: android, smartcard, fingerprint

I am using idemia tablet sdk for cardreading and fingerprint android. I am getting below error

**E/com.idemia.smartcardlibrary.SmartCardLibrary: Open failed : Please use connect API first.**

Any idea on what i am doing wrong ?

I tried to initialize the usb and than trying to connect the card . But i am not getting the result for Libmartcard.aar

Comment: Better contact IDEMIA?

Comment: But i am using ICA toolkit plugin

Comment: On an IDEMIA tablet right? A toolkit is just that, a toolkit. That's not the same thing as a knowledgebase or developer support. I'm not saying that you shouldn't post here, but chances are that there is much more knowledge at IDEMIA internally, and this seems product specific. The chance of bumping into an expert with this specific knowledge on [so] is just not that high.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.